# Split taxonomy terms in two facet filters

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search, 9

English is not my first language, so please be patient.

I'd like to ask for assistance to split my taxonomy terms in two facet filters.

**Context:**

- Drupal Core v9.2.6
- Acquia Search v3.0.5
- Acquia Connector v3.0.4
- Search API v8.x-1.21
- Search API Solr v4.2.1
- Search API Pages v8.x-1.0-beta3
- Search API Solr Admin v4.2.1
- Facets v8.x-1.8

I have configured correctly the listed modules and set a functional Search feature for an Acquia site. Now I need to make some editions to our Facet filters.

I have a taxonomy for recipes that's listed like:

1. Cake

- Red Velvet
- Milkyway
- Pineapple

2. Muffin

- Sweet
- Choco-party

3. Milkshake

- Marshmallow
- M&M's
- Almond milk

I need to set two facet filters (one dependent on the other) where the user can filter first by dessert type (parent taxonomy), then by flavor (children taxonomy).

[image: Search Results View]

Right now my facet filter only displays all the desserts (parent taxonomy) in a single dropdown, ***any ideas on how to split them?***

Please let me know if additional details are required.

**References:**

https://drupalize.me/tutorial/create-facet?p=3319

https://drupalize.me/tutorial/create-facet-using-taxonomy?p=3319

Comment: Is this question "How do I split the taxonomy terms in a facet?" or "How do I use Solr locally with Acquia Dev Desktop?"  Those are totally different questions.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickKenny, you are right, I'll split the information to make two separate questions.